# Ether.js - When setting an allowance in Metamask, subsequent transactions always fail with an error that the allowance is 0

Tags: ethereum, redux-thunk, metamask, ethers.js

I'm setting a up a contract, and asking for user approval when initiating a transaction using a Redux Thunk.  Metamask asks the user to set an allowance; however, after setting an allowance the transaction fails with an error `Transfer amount exceeds allowance, amount approved 0`.

I believe this is a race condition, but would like to sanity-check my code because looking at network activity and Redux logs it seems like actions are completing in correct time.

Thunk:

```
export const getMetamaskApproval =
  (
    tokenAddress: string,
    walletAddress: string,
    amountWei: number,
    decimals: number
  ) =>
  async (dispatch: any) => {
    try {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(
        (window as any).ethereum
      );
      await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);

      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      const address = await signer.getAddress();

      const erc20Abi = [
        "function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public returns (bool)",
      ];

      const iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(erc20Abi);
      const data = iface.encodeFunctionData("approve", [
        walletAddress,
        ethers.utils.parseUnits(amountWei.toString(), decimals),
      ]);

      const transaction = {
        to: tokenAddress,
        data: data,
        from: address,
        gasPrice: await provider.getGasPrice(),
      };

      const txResponse = await signer.sendTransaction(transaction);
      const receipt = await provider.waitForTransaction(txResponse.hash);

      if (receipt) {
        dispatch(_metamaskApproval(receipt));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

I have tried refactoring my ABI, as well as verifying that the approval transaction was completed on Etherscan.